# Is there any way to run async function for a static variable in class?

Tags: dart

```
class UserInfo with ChangeNotifier {
  static final connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
      'mydomain',
      1234,
      'mydatabasedb',
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password');
  User info;

  somestaticfunction() async{
    await connection.open(); // which will open connection once for all
  }
}
```

what I tried:

1. open a connection for each userinfo class instance but not able as it is Future function so it is not opening connection before using it.
2. opening the connection in every method so I can use it, but saying reopening connection which is already open.

what I want:
some static function which will run one time for all class instances and all can use this connection.

Comment: Are you looking for a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Future` will only ever complete with the same value. Try making the type of your field a `Future`, and `await` it in each place you want to use the connection.

```
class UserInfo with ChangeNotifier {
  static final connection = _createConnection();
  User info;

  static Future<PostgreSQLConnection> _createConnection() async {
    final connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
      'mydomain',
      1234,
      'mydatabasedb',
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password');
    await connection.open();
    return connection;
  }
}
```

A static that is `final` is initialized the first time it is used.

Comment: Not sure why it's accepted answer. But the proposed solution does not work.